# How does containerization software like Docker translate CPU instructions?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, emulation, instructions

I recently ran into a bug where a python library used a certain CPU instruction which existed on one x86 processor but not on another, resulting in an unexpected crash of the program (*Illegal instruction*) on one system but not on another. That had me thinking of the benefits of containerization to create a well-defined run-time environment for my software. But my brain ground to a halt when I realized how low level this is, and I could not figure out from reasoning nor from reading on the internet, as to what level the isolation of software like docker goes.

## Question

So my questions is: **Would a containerization software, like Docker or LXC, be able to emulate an instruction which does not exist on the physical hardware?** And would a full VM be able to deal with it, if a container could not?

## Anecdotal information

Thought I'd fill in the blanks, just because people were curious.

The specific scenario I was caught by was when trying to apply Reed-Solomon erasure coding to a data object.  I'm using the [PyECLib](https://github.com/openstack/pyeclib) library which implements Vandermonde Reed-Solomon via the `liberasurecode` library (which in turn uses [jerasure](http://jerasure.org/jerasure-2.0/), I believe).

### Minimal Working Example

This piece of code runs without errors on a compatible processor, but produces the `Illegal instruction` exception on some older processors:

```
from pyeclib.ec_iface import ECDriver

ec_driver = ECDriver(k=1, m=5, ec_type='liberasurecode_rs_vand')
ec_driver.encode(b'foo')
```

### Environment

I'm using Python 3.6 on multiple Linux platforms. The notable case where things wreak havoc is in an LXC container running Fedora 25 on the processor specified below, but I'd bet LXC and Fedora has little to do with it.

I've tried both pyeclib 1.4 and 1.1, and have the same thing happen.

These processors makes my program crash:

- Intel Xeon X5660
- Intel Xeon X3363
- Intel Xeon E5405
- Intel Xeon X3430
- Intel Xeon E3110

Here are some processors which works fine:

- Intel Xeon E31220
- Intel Core i7-7500U

Comment: I don't know much about container software but I would take a guess that Docker can't handle translating CPU instructions, and it just executes the library as-is. Maybe the Python library is calling a lower level library implemented in x86 assembly that uses special extensions (I would be interested to find out which specific extensions, I haven't heard of a problem like this in a long time). Also minor grammar nitpick, your title would be more correct grammatically as something like "How *does* containerization software like Docker handle (maybe use translate or emulate?) CPU instructions".

Comment: Containerisation is not a VM/emulation.  It's literally just a sandboxed process.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess the same way your OS keeps your code from accessing memory that's not yours, causing segfaults.

Comment: @WardSegers the thing is, the OS is very capable of remembering which pages of memory a process has access to, I'm not sure it is smart enough to say, e.g., "We just detected a SSE only instruction, here's a huge chunk of standard x86 instructions that do the same thing, that we know the CPU can support". IIRC typically CPUs do that in *hardware*, as in, the CPU would say "sure I support SSE" and then run a long string of microcode that (e.g.) Intel, not Linux, would deem as equivalent, not the OS. I'm not sure the OS knows enough about the CPU's hardware to optimize something like that.

Comment: ...I'd say if anything what I mentioned above would be the *compiler's* job, not the OS's job.

Comment: @jrh Thanks for pointing out the typos. :) I'll update my post explaining my specific scenario, just to sate your curiosity.

Comment: mm, it's an open source library, neat, maybe I can go into more detail now. Is there a specific build you used? If you built it, what architecture did you compile it on? Any customized settings? Maybe there's a way to build it that would work for all of your CPUs.

Comment: I didn't explicitly compile anything, I just put the code from my MWE into a file and pointed python towards it: `$ python3.6 test_pyeclib.py`. So if python actually compiles things for me, it would be on the same architecture which it was run on. Can dig up some version numbers for you later.

Comment: @lindhe what does MWE stand for? Minimal Working Environment?

Comment: Minimal Working Example

Comment: @jrh `pyeclib==1.5.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Containers don't translate instructions. A program running in a container is exactly the same as any other program running on the same machine, except that it has separate ("namespaced") instances of certain things, like the filesystem, the network stack, and the system hostname. The CPU isn't emulated or virtualized (any more than usual, anyway.)

Virtual machines *can* support instructions not supported on the host machine, but they do not *necessarily* do so. If they do, it will usually come at a substantial cost in performance.

Answer (score 4):

The practical answer is that no, no current product is capable of this.

It's not weird to wonder. In fact, not very long ago it was common for ARM processors to support exactly this functionality even without a VM. On ARM, floating-point used to be optional, but on processors without FP the "invalid opertion"  exception could be reliably trapped. If you had linked a FP emulation library, that could then take over and recover from the exception.

The more modern approach is to use alternate code paths. Just compile two versions of every function that would benefit from the non-common instructions. At runtime, check the available CPU, and use this to decide which set of functions to use. A variation is to pack these functions in two DLLs/.so's, and load one of the two depending on CPU.

Comment: There were soft-float libraries for x86 (back when the 387 was still an optional piece of hardware) that worked on the same principle. As you say, it doesn't require a VM, just sufficient privileges to trap the "invalid instruction" exception. But it's not terribly efficient, or very convenient from the implementer's point of view.

Comment: Typo: "invalid opertion"? Do you mean "invalid operation" or "invalid opcode"? I find it interesting that recent ARM CPUs would leave it to libraries to trap system faults and run alternate code, floating point support has been around since the Pentium... I'm surprised they didn't implement microcode in the CPU for that even if it was incredibly slow compared to dedicated floating point hardware... even the cheapo Motorola 6800 CPU I used in college had floating point division, it took an eternity but it worked...

Comment: @jrh ARM fills the microcontroller niche as well as the CPU one, and floating-point is very often just not needed. You can still buy Cortex-M0 chips without FPU — they're very small, very cheap, and use very little power. Floating-point was made non-optional in ARMv8, but only *big* chips like those used in phones and other high-end devices are on ARMv8 at this point.