# How Docker behave with SIMD

Tags: docker, virtualization, simd

I'm wondering how docker behaves when code inside the container is compiled with SSE or NEON optimization. What happens if I push this image to a docker registry and pull it from a platform where those instructions are not available ?

Comment: What would happen if you ran a binary outside of docker on a platform without those instructions?

Comment: The binary would raise SIGILL when the CPU faults on an illegal instruction.  You can test this on any hardware by making a binary with an illegal instruction in it.  (e.g. x86 `asm("ud2");` )

Comment: Don't know how to say a question is repeated but the first answer from the following link addresses this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516477/how-does-containerization-software-like-docker-translate-cpu-instructions